# Mock API calls with Retrofit + coroutines + Mockk

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

**Later Edit**

I ended up to have my api service methods `suspended` and refactor my code as suggested by @LordRaydenMK.

The reason for using the library `ru.gildor.coroutines:kotlin-coroutines-retrofit` it the first place was out of pure convenience **AND** it was before retrofit released the version which would support for coroutines.

---

**Original Question**

I have been trying for a couple of days to mock the API calls with no success. I'm using the following libraries:

- `retrofit` - i think we are all familiar with it
- `ru.gildor.coroutines:kotlin-coroutines-retrofit` - for a couple of useful coroutine extensions
- `io.mockk:mockk` - for mocking

It is a simple case of mocking the API response

```kotlin
interface ApiService {

  @GET
  fun getMyData(@Header("x-value") myValue: String): Call<String>
}
```

```kotlin
class Usecase(api: ApiService) {

  suspend fun execute() {
    val result = api.getMyData(value: String).awaitResult()
    // do smth with that result for now just return it
   return (result as Result.Ok).value
  }
}
```

```kotlin
class UseCaseTest {
   private val api = mockk<ApiService>()

  @Test
  fun testApiCall() {
    coEvery { api.getMyData(any()) } returns CallTest.buildSuccess("you did it!")

    val result = useCase.execute()
    assertEquals(result, "you did it!")
  }
}
```

In the example above the test hangs on the awaitResult extension method.

What i have tried so far with no luck:

- mockkStatic(ru.gildor.coroutines.retrofit.CallAwait) but with no success
- mockk `Call<String>` and do a `coEvery { mockedCall.awaitResult() } returns ....`

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing and a pair of fresh eyes will spot it from a mile away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing:

`getMyData` is NOT a `suspend` function so probably you should NOT be using `coEvery` when mocking it (tho I'm not a Mockk user).

That being said, Retrofit does support `suspend` functions natively, so you could do:

```
interface ApiService {

  @GET
  suspend fun getMyData(@Header("x-value") myValue: String): String
}
```

that means no need for `awaitResult` in your use case. In this scenario you do need `coEvery` when  mocking it.

Comment: Fair point, the `getMyData` could go away with `every` function, but that does not change a lot the things. About using in the `ApiService` suspend, it's an idea but it would mean to massively change the codebase.

Comment: Did you try converting `getMyData` to `suspend`? My theory is something might be wrong with calling `awaitResult()` on a fake/mock object. This would remove the need for it.

Comment: I did, but the change would cascade into a rabbit hole of changes in the actual implementation.  There is for sure something wrong with the mocked objects while `awaitResult` during debugging the result is returned correctly from the apiService and then it hangs into `awaitResult`

Comment: I ended up to switch and have my api service methods suspended and refactor my code. The reason for using the library `ru.gildor.coroutines:kotlin-coroutines-retrofit` was out of pure convenience AND it was before retrofit released the version which would support for coroutines. I'll mark your answer as the accepted one